# mysql 5.5 innodb_data_file_directory

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to spread mysql data across two disks as follows:

```
innodb_data_file_path =  /var/lib/mysql/ibdata:1000G;/disk2/mysql/ibdata2:1000M:autoextend
```

mysql attempts to create a new file of 1000G when starting, however it fails silently after writing about 250GB of empty data to ibdata.

Question:

1. is this due to single file size limit? the OS is centos 6 (ext3 fs)  if not what could be the cause of the starting failure.  There is enough disk space on the main disk. no extra error log is provided.
2. is there any other quick and dirty way to spread the data across two disks?

Edit: added df info:

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             1.8T  308G  1.4T  18% /
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             471M   92M  355M  21% /boot
/dev/sdb1             1.8T  332G  1.4T  20% /disk2
```

Comment: Might be an ovious question, but did you check you had enough free space on the volume you are writing the file to?

Comment: @Jasper: yes, please see what my df -h shows in the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think your problem is with the ext3 filesystem.  With a 2k blocksize the maximum file size is 256gb.  It looks very likely that you are hitting that limit, which is why innodb fails when it tries to increase the filesize.

Comment: is it possible to increase block size without distroying existing data?

Comment: No there is no way.  You would have to create a new volume and copy the data, or backup the data, create the new filesystem and restore.